# Why I always get a Promise form my return value?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Below is my function

```
async function test() {
const data= [];
for (let i = 0; i <= 5; i = i + 1) {
    const payload: any = await postExampleApi(i);
        data.push(payload);
    }
    return data;
}

export const getData =  test().then((data) => {
    console.log(data);
    return data;
});
```

I try to call api six times with different params(number 0 - 5) each times.

I can have my data array from console.log, however, when I import this getData function from another file, I always get a Promise{...} not data array.

Did I do something wrong?

Comment: why do you thing you should not get a promise?

Comment: because async on function guarantees function returns promise - it's in the *documentation* - oh yes, and you can't return a synchronous value when asynchronous code is involved - promises *do not make asynchronous code synchronous*

Comment: Please show the code which imports `getData()` and calls it.

Comment: Seems like you wanna save the function result `data` into `getData`. As of now, there is no easy way to export from the result of an asynchronous function. What you want is to export `test` function then import & call the function like `await test()` when you need the data.

Comment: @JaromandaX we can actually return a synchronous value using some nasty while loop though.

Comment: no, you can't do that

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you do this :

```
let x = promise().then(cb)
```

You get "x" as promise only. All you should do is when requiring this file, do a "dot then" to get the data.

So wherever you require the file, do this :

```
let test = require('./test');
test.then((dataArray) => console.log(data));
```

Comment: Please take time to put a comment for the downvotes.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are calling a async function `getData` === `async test()`, if you don't want to deal with the `then`, you can make your call like `await getData()`